# Move /usr to SSD

Tags: arch-linux, partition, ssd

I have an SSD and regular HDD drive in my laptop. The SSD drive is not used at all; it is not even being mounted. I am using Arch Linux. I'd like to start using the SSD, and from what I have read I believe mounting `/usr` there would be a good idea. My question is: with an installed system, how do I go about setting up the `/usr` partition on the SSD and moving the current files to this new location?

Comment: You could [use the SSD as a cache](http://askubuntu.com/q/252140/)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Note:* These are generalized instructions. Some comments below indicate that your specific distro may or may not have problems with you doing this. That is why the backup in step 4 is recommended.

1. Format SSD. What file system to use on SSD is another question.
2. Boot from a rescue CD and mount up both HD and SSD.
3. `rsync -avP` `/usr` from HD to SSD.
4. Move `/usr` to `/usr_backup` just in case things fail.
5. Create empty `/usr` on HD for a mount point.
6. Update `/etc/fstab` on HD to mount `/usr` from the SSD.
7. Reboot and hope.
8. Don't touch `/usr/lost+found/`

Comment: If you consider keeping the contents of the old /usr, then you can skip step 4 and 5. Mounting the SSD partition on top of /usr will hide the old contents. Only keep in mind that it will get outdated as the system is updated.

Comment: But, by creating a new /usr_backup, you can delete it once everything is verified to be working, and free up some space in the root.

Comment: For step 2, you can just reboot into single-user mode; you don't need a rescue disk for this. (In GRUB, append `single` to the kernel options line.) This avoids the need for the "mount HD" part of the step, too; it should be mounted as part of a single-user boot.

Comment: Note: this is _not_ straightforward. Having `/usr` on a separate partion [is not supported in Arch](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1006924#p1006924), which means that you will need to take some additional steps...

Comment: After step 6, you should verify whether mounting the ssd as /usr works before rebooting.

Comment: @jasonwryan That's not true anymore, it's [https://mailman.archlinux.org/pipermail/arch-general/2012-January/024124.html](supported now). This also includes some additional steps not mention in this answer.

Comment: @Wieland H you are [quite right](http://mailman.archlinux.org/pipermail/arch-general/2012-January/024124.html)...

Comment: For `/usr`, you can even do the copy from a live system. Just don't install or upgrade any software while doing the copy, and `/usr` won't change under your feet.

Comment: @antje-m Leaving it behind to be overwritten is just asking for trouble. Especially if the distro doesn't fully support the `/usr` being another partition - as it is run from the initial RAM image, it may be loading libraries (or config information) that the user has since updated/upgraded. Seems to be asking for trouble.